# Calling a function from HTML to Python file

Tags: python, django

I have a index.html page with a list of "cards", where each card have a "Click to Select" link.

When user click in this link i'd like to call a function in python to select this item, see:

```
def selectItem(request, item):
    #so something with this item
```

so, in my html pagE:

```
<div class="card-action">
                            <a href="{{ selectItem(myitem) }}">Selecionar</a>
                        </div>
```

This don't work. What is the right way to do it ?

Comment: You need to pass an URL to the view, so `{% url 'view_name' item_id=myitem.id %}` given that is a view, and you do the proper handling of the URL. Furthermore you can not just pass the object, since that object can not be "shipped". You can for example use the `id`, and the do the proper processing in the view (to turn the `id` back into an object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not call a function like that. A browser requests data with an HTTP request, and the server answers with an (HTTP) response. Such requests have a URL, and Django can route the request - with the URL - to the right view that will calculate a response.

We thus need to construct a view that can then be called. Your call is already quite close:

```
# app/views.py

from django.http import HttpResponse

def select_item(request, item_id):
    # so something with this item_id
    # ...
    return HttpResponse()
```

Since most objects are not serializable (and usually you do not want that anyway, since it would expose a lot of (potentially sensitive) data to the user, we thus need to work with an `id` (an identifier that is for example stored in the database that *corresponds* to an object).

The response contains the data in the response. Frequently that is HTML code that is then rendered by the browser.

Now in `urls.py`, we can specify how the url looks like, for example:

```
# app/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from app.views import select_item

urlpatterns = [
    path('select_item/<int:item_id>/', select_item, name='select_item_view'),
    # ...
]
```

The `urlpatterns` need to be included in the root `urlpatterns` (in the project root).

Now in the HTML template, we can generate the URL that matches with this view, something similar to:

```
<div class="card-action">
  <a href="{% url 'select_item_view' item_id=myitem.id %}">Selecionar</a>
</div>
```

Django will then make sure that the `href` points to an URL that refers to the `select_item` view with the correct parameter.

Comment: Very useful answer, thanks. If you can help I have another doubt. Should I create a view_select.py or put all in same view.py file ? I think that view.py very verbose

Comment: Usually all views are put in `views.py`, but you can indeed write different files. Wrtiting every view in a separate file would however be more the "Java-ish" approach.

Comment: Thanks again Willem